# How to find out the outgoing server and port from outlook?

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft-outlook-2007, smtp

I have Windows 7 and running outlook 2007 (wtih exchange mailserver). I want to switch to Thunderbird. Have spent some time to search both on SU and google without really finding a succinct answer to my question.  When I setup thunderbird, I got existing emails in my inbox and there is a outgoing server on Thunderbird. But when I try to send an email I get:

```
The message could not be sent because connecting to SMTP server 
xxx.mycompany.com failed. The server may be unavailable or is refusing 
SMTP connections. Please verify that your SMTP server settings are 
correct and try again, or contact the server administrator.
```

Using `ProcessExplorer`  I found out that `Outlook` uses an IP with a strange port `52084`. I have tried this IP and port as an outgoing SMTP server in Thunderbird. And when I do that, the above error does not pop up immediately but I get an indefinite progress bar showing thunderbird trying to send message.  Also tried with the same IP ports `25`, `465` and `587`, `585` with no success. When I use port `995`, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred sending mail: The mail server sent an 
incorrect greeting:  +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service 
is ready..
```

Port `993`:

```
An error occurred sending mail: The mail server sent an incorrect 
greeting:  * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready..
```

Comment: The port you are seeing is dynamic and on your side, not on the SMTP server side.

Comment: @Matteo I was thinking the same, thanks for confirming this. How do I find out the port that is actually used?

Comment: Also try secure connection ports 585 and 995

Comment: @user3111525 What's your name kid?

Comment: @Firee Frank, why?

Comment: If you have Exchange server, why are you using POP3/SMTP and moving to Thunderbird? Exchange is expensive and if your company is not using MAPI / Outlook Anywhere, you're missing all its best sharing features - shared contacts and calendars, etc.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Good point! However, I am preparing to migrate to Linux.

Comment: If you want to find out how Outlook is configured then go into your Account settings in Outlook and make note of the ports ands settings.

Comment: @user3111525 Frank, its just that id's like 'userXXX' seem very robotic, a human touch/image is required sometimes... This is Sam here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it out. Use port `587` and set the option `Connection Security` to `None` in `Outgoing Server(SMTP) => Security and Authentication`.

For those wondering, here how it looks at my end:

[image]

Comment: So your mail provider has moved off port 25 for their submission port. Now you know :)

Comment: @Rudolph Have to wait for two days!